# Concatenate comma separated strings using STUFF

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stuff

I want to concatenate comma-separated string. I have a query where I am using the function to get the staff.

Currently, I am using `[dbo].fn_fullname(A.REFNO`) as Staff to get the staff but I want to include some conditions if the count of `cast(S.SCH_NO as varchar) as ReferenceIdentifier` is greater than 1 then concatenate the value. But not sure how it can be achieved inside the view itself.

Here I am trying to use `STUFF` to concatenate.

Here is the query:

```sql
    Alter View vw_TestDB
    AS
       select 
           NEWID() as UniqueKey,
           P.ID as Number, 
           cast(S.SCH_NO as varchar) as ReferenceIdentifier, 
           cast(S.START_D as datetime2) as StartDateTime,                                      
            staff = STUFF((
            SELECT ',' + [dbo].fn_fullname(A.REFNO)
            FROM [dbo].[vw_TESTDB]
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ), 1, 1, '')
        FROM [dbo].[vw_TestDB]
        group by ReferenceIdentifier
        having count(ReferenceIdentifier)>1,
    
         [dbo].fn_fullname(A.REFNO) as Staff,
         
    from [dbo].V_SCHEDULES S WITH (NOLOCK)
    inner join [dbo].V_PAT P WITH (NOLOCK) on P.PAT_REFNO = S.PAT_REFNO
```

Here the function:

```sql
    ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_fullname]
    (
        @refno as numeric(10, 0)
    )
    RETURNS varchar(100)
    AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @name     as varchar(100)

        SELECT  @name = Stuff(Coalesce(' ' + 
                CASE 
                    WHEN proca.TITLE_REFNO = 3104 
                        THEN NULL
                    ELSE
                        NullIf(dbo.fn_rfval(proca.TITLE_REFNO), '')
                END,
                '') +
                Coalesce(' ' + proca.forename, '') +
                Coalesce(' ' + proca.surname, ''),
                1, 
                1,
                '') 
        FROM    dbo.v_carers_active proca (nolock)
        WHERE   refno = @refno

        return @name
    END

    GO
```

Here are sample data

| UniqueKey | Number | ReferenceIdentifier | StartDateTime | staff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 70DB83D1-2900-4CF1-9CC4-CA6948AC0E91 | A4286 | 2182823 | 2015-03-26 08:00:00.0000000 | Ms S Taylor |
| 310745CB-4724-4724-A5F0-7D9088317E58 | A4286 | 2182823 | 2015-03-26 08:00:00.0000000 | Ms D Kirkpatrick |
| CA6DDB25-AADD-4FC1-ABAA-2AF84016E6E5 | A4286 | 2182834 | 2015-03-19 08:00:00.0000000 | Ms D Kirkpatrick |
| 6A3C0A3B-EAA3-4523-B4FD-2882E2C02B4A | A4286 | 2182844 | 2015-03-30 08:00:00.0000000 | Mrs Nel McKinnon |
| 6399662A-EC4D-4993-8D4F-0BC396D12C2C | A4286 | 2182844 | 2015-03-30 08:00:00.0000000 | Ms Deb Kirkpatrick |

Expected output

| UniqueKey | Number | ReferenceIdentifier | StartDateTime | staff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 70DB83D1-2900-4CF1-9CC4-CA6948AC0E91 | A4286 | 2182823 | 2015-03-26 08:00:00.0000000 | Ms S Taylor,Ms D Kirkpatrick |
| CA6DDB25-AADD-4FC1-ABAA-2AF84016E6E5 | A4286 | 2182834 | 2015-03-19 08:00:00.0000000 | Ms D Kirkpatrick |
| 6A3C0A3B-EAA3-4523-B4FD-2882E2C02B4A | A4286 | 2182844 | 2015-03-30 08:00:00.0000000 | Mrs Nel McKinnon,Ms Deb Kirkpatrick |

Comment: `STUFF` doesn't concatenate. `FOR XML PATH('')` is doing all of the heavy lifting. `STUFF` is just removing the leading comma on the final string.

Comment: This is the same as your previous question, now deleted. You need to improve whatever was requested last time.

Comment: @DaleK, can you please show me a way to do this. I am not getting an idea.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, can you please show me how it can be achieved.

Comment: What happen to `Ms D Kirkpatrick` UniqueKey of `310745CB-4724-4724-A5F0-7D9088317E58` ?

Comment: Hi @Squirrel, We will hide the unique key. I am more interested in concatenating staff if they have a duplicate `ReferenceIdentifier`.I know that I can't use stuff like this way as I can't use the same view name there. `staff = STUFF((SELECT ',' + [dbo].fn_fullname(A.REFNO)  FROM [dbo].[vw_TESTDB]  FOR XML PATH('')
            ), 1, 1, '')   FROM [dbo].[vw_TestDB]  group by ReferenceIdentifier
        having count(ReferenceIdentifier)>1,`  .I am looking a way to do this.

Comment: @Aarav if you use SQL Server 2017 and later you can use `STRING_AGG` insteaf of `FOR XML`. Even then, the question is incomplete - how do you pick the UniqueKey? Is `StartDateTime` part of the grouping or not? Or do you only want to group by `ReferenceIdentifier` and then return eg the `MIN` or `MAX` value for all other columns?

Comment: @Aarav in any case `NOLOCK` is a serious bug. It doesn't mean `take no locks` it means `read dirty and duplicate data while taking extra locks and throwing randomly`. If you have performance issues, you need to fix them, not cover them up

Comment: Hi @PanagiotisKanavos, will hide the uniqueKey. Yes, I am using SQL Server 2017. Basically, I want to concatenate the staff if `ReferenceIdentifier` is duplicate. But If you see my question, I am using the function to get the staff. But I am not sure how it can be achieved inside the View.

Comment: @Aarav which means you don't need `FOR XML` at all. Have you tried using `STRING_AGG`? `SELECt ReferenceIdentifier, Min(UniqueKey), Min(Number), Min(StartDatetime), STRING_AGG(staff,',') from ... GROUP BY ReferenceIdentifier`

Comment: Hi @PanagiotisKanavos, can you please invite me for a chat if you have a minute then.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Not quite understand what you wanted. Based on the sample data and expected output, it seems like you wanted

```
SELECT  t.[Number], t.[ReferenceIdentifier], t.[StartDatetime],
        STUFF (
                 (SELECT ',' + [dbo].fn_fullname(x.REFNO)
                  FROM   yourtable AS x
                  WHERE  x.[Number] = t.[Number]
                  AND    x.[ReferenceIdentifier] = t.[ReferenceIdentifier]
                  AND    x.[StartDatetime] = t.[StartDatetime]
                  FOR XML PATH('')),
               1, 1, '') AS Staff
FROM    yourtable t
GROUP BY t.[Number], t.[ReferenceIdentifier], t.[StartDatetime]
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can I use the same View name inside STUFF function.

Comment: Not if you are using this query for the view. You need to reference the base table name. And not the view name

Comment: And if you are using `SQL Server 2017`, check out `STRING_AGG` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: HI @Squirrel, One more thing to ask. As you can see that I am using a function inside ` STUFF ( (SELECT ',' + [dbo].fn_fullname(x.REFNO) FROM   yourtable AS x
                  WHERE  x.[Number] = t.[Number] AND    x.[ReferenceIdentifier] = t.[ReferenceIdentifier] AND    x.[StartDatetime] = t.[StartDatetime] FOR XML PATH('')),
               1, 1, '') AS Staff. Can I use `dbo.v_carers_active proca` in place of table name in your query. It would be great if you can use my function query table as well in your answer.

Comment: Frankly, I have no idea. I don't know where are those columns like `REFNO` , `Number` etc are from which table. What I have shown here is a typical query for similar using `FOR XML PATH`.

Comment: Hi @squirrel, can you please invite me for a chat. I want to show the query.